# Docker Build Service failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified using Azure Private Agent

Tags: docker, azure

I'm working on a big project that uses docker containers and docker-compose for the services.  I'm also using Azure DevOps for the build and release.

When I build my project using a hosted VS2017 Agent, it works perfectly with no errors.  Now I created a private agent through Azure DevTest Labs and I'm using it as an agent to build.  The build now gives an error "##[error]Service 'annotation.api' failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified". In the directory I can see the files are there and the exact same repo worked on the hosted agent.

I've been reading online and some mentioned that it may be a permissions issue but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential causes for this problem.

The two most common seem to be (1) a .dockerignore file that is causing the build context to ignore the file you are trying to copy, and (2) an attempt to copy a file that is outside the current build context (by default, the directory from which you are running the docker build command).

So, in general, attempting to `COPY ../dir/file*` will fail with this error, not referencing that the actual problem is not that the file does not exist, but that it is not within the build context.  If you remove the asterisk, you may get the more useful

```
COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context
```

Comment: In my case, I was trying to `COPY ../package* ./` and this was definitely the cause of the issue.